# How to open multiselected files on Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have alot of excel files I want to selecte Three files and show them in datagridview, I tried with code but my code show only the last one,e.g I have 1,2,3 files, datagridview show just file 3.
What should I do here please,

enter code here

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
     {

       OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
       openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files, Text Files, Excel Files| *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xml; *.txt; "; ;
       openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
       if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                //tb_path is textbox
                tb_path.Text = file;
               // excelFilePath_com = tb_path.Text;
               }

           string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    con.Open();
                    drop_down_sheet.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);                
   //dro_down_sheet is combobox to choose which sheet to import 
                    drop_down_sheet.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
                    drop_down_sheet.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";


            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
         "Important Note",
         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         MessageBoxIcon.Error,
         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code well, you are looping through all `openFileDialog1.FileNames` *before* doing anything with them. If you encapsulate everything in your `foreach` loop, you should be able to use all selected files. For example:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        //tb_path is textbox
        tb_path.Text = file;
        // excelFilePath_com = tb_path.Text;
        string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        drop_down_sheet.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        //dro_down_sheet is combobox to choose which sheet to import 
        drop_down_sheet.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        drop_down_sheet.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it still the same problem, datagridview show me only the last file is selected.